Gitlab pipeline: stop looping the pipeline
I have come to find out, my pipeline goes on loop. here is my pipeline
here is what happening,
Problem Summary


Pipeline Stages and Goals:  •   Merge Request Submission:   •   When a Merge Request (MR) is submitted, the pipeline should run tests to
ensure the changes are correct.   •   Merge to Master:    •   After merging
an MR to the master branch:   •   The bump_version job should run to
increment the version in app/meta.py.     •   The build-prod job should run
to build and push Docker images.  •   The pipeline should stop after the
build-prod job.
Current Behavior:   •   When an MR is submitted, the tests run successfully.    •   When the MR is merged to master, the bump_version job
runs, followed by the build-prod job.     •   The build-prod job runs
again, leading to an infinite loop, causing the entire pipeline to
re-trigger.
Suspected Cause:    •   The bump_version job creates a commit on the master branch, which triggers the build-prod job.  •   The creation of a
Git tag by the bump_version job also triggers the entire pipeline
again.

Desired Behavior
•   Ensure that the pipeline does not re-trigger itself after the
bump_version and build-prod jobs.     •   The pipeline should stop after
the build-prod job when the version bump commit and tag are created.
Requirements:

Merge Request (MR) Submission:  •   Run tests.
Merge to Master:    •   Run bump_version job.   •   Run build-prod job.     •   Stop the pipeline after build-prod without retriggering.



stages:
  - build-ci-image
  - lint
  - test
  - bump_version
  - build
  - deploy

variables:

build_ci_image:
  stage: build-ci-image
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.14.0-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - /kaniko/executor ...."
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      changes:
        - docker/Dockerfile
        - requirements.dev.txt
        - requirements.txt

.python_job:
  image: ....
  interruptible: true
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'

lint:
  stage: lint
  extends: .python_job
  script:
    - make lint

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - make coverage

bump_version:
  stage: bump_version
  image: bump2version
  script:
    - git remote set-url ...
    - bump2version $VERSION_PART --current-version $(grep -oP '__VERSION__ = "\K[0-9.]+(?=")' app/meta.py) app/meta.py
    - git push origin HEAD:master --tags
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/meta.py
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^Bump\ version:/
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"

build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.14.0-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
    - ....
  script:
    - /kaniko/executor ..."
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'

build-prod:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.14.0-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
    - ....
  script:
    - |
      new_version=$(grep -o '__VERSION__ = "[0-9.]\+"' app/meta.py | sed 's/__VERSION__ = "//;s/"//')
      /kaniko/executor ...."
  dependencies:
    - bump_version
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/meta.py
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'

deploy-staging:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: 
  image:
    name: bitnami/kubectl:latest
    entrypoint: ['']
  script:
    - kubectl ....
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG


You can prevent the pipeline from retriggering after the bump_version and build-prod jobs, by making some adjustments to ensure that the new commit and tag created by bump_version do not trigger the pipeline again. I have modified your yaml file.
stages:
  - build-ci-image
  - lint
  - test
  - bump_version
  - build
  - deploy

variables:

build_ci_image:
  stage: build-ci-image
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.14.0-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - /kaniko/executor ...."
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      changes:
        - docker/Dockerfile
        - requirements.dev.txt
        - requirements.txt

.python_job:
  image: ....
  interruptible: true
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'

lint:
  stage: lint
  extends: .python_job
  script:
    - make lint

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - make coverage

bump_version:
  stage: bump_version
  image: bump2version
  script:
    - git remote set-url ...
    - bump2version $VERSION_PART --current-version $(grep -oP '__VERSION__ = "\K[0-9.]+(?=")' app/meta.py) app/meta.py
    - git push origin HEAD:master --tags
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/meta.py
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE !~ /^Bump version:/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'

build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.14.0-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
    - ....
  script:
    - /kaniko/executor ..."
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "tag"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'

build-prod:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.14.0-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
    - ....
  script:
    - |
      new_version=$(grep -o '__VERSION__ = "[0-9.]\+"' app/meta.py | sed 's/__VERSION__ = "//;s/"//')
      /kaniko/executor ...."
  dependencies:
    - bump_version
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/meta.py
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE !~ /^Bump version:/'

deploy-staging:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: 
  image:
    name: bitnami/kubectl:latest
    entrypoint: ['']
  script:
    - kubectl ....
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "tag"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'


hello, im testing the pipeline now, when i submit a MR bump version also running along side with test. when MR submitted I dont want to run bump version only test and when MR is merged bump version and build prod should run.

@user3073987 I have modified the code let's see what happens

fantastic, it worked, now small thing to tackle, when the git tag is created whole pipeline triggers which is fine, but build and deploy-staging also executing, even here its says on dev branch, can we fix this?

@user3073987 I have updated the code for you

Thanks again, still same. when tag is created, build and deploy-staging.
is it because of this     - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'

@user3073987 you can try removing it let's see what happens

all good! thanks for the help, you goated
